# Loading mask, that disables underlying html elements

Tags: html, css

I want to create loader mask for all page. I need to get the elements under the mask were not available. But now I can click buttons. you can see all on the image.

here is css of mask:

```
div#mask {
    z-index:9999;
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

it's div with 100% width, and height of window. How to fix ui block?

[image]

Comment: Which plugin (library) is this by the way? I would appreciate if anyone will answer this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given this:

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to place it with position absolute and set the height as well. So this works fine:

```
<style>

div.mask {
    position:           absolute;
    z-index:            1;
    top:                0;
    left:               0;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
    background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

</style>

<a href="">Can't be clicked</a>

<div id="mask" class="mask"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `pointer-events: none;` CSS rule

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score -1):

```
div.mask
{
    position:           fixed;
    z-index:            1;
    top:                0;
    left:               0;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
    background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

Instead of **absolute**, you can put **fixed**